# Trying to find a book about a young girl who is from a family of witches

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to find a book that I read probably in the late 90's early 2000's.

It's an urban fantasy. The premise is that there is a young girl who finds out she comes from a family of witches.

I only remember some details:

- There is a special house that all of the women in the family go to.
- The girl has a grandmother with dementia who wanders off all the time, but when she goes into the house her dementia goes away.
- The girl has an older sister called Helena or Helen, which gets shortened to Hell. (I don't think she's magic)
- I think it might be set in or near Wales, as they eat Laverbread.
- The girl is given a necklace which is a gold disk, maybe with a small gem set into it, that's special in some way.

Comment: I don't know it for sure, but it sounds like the sort of thing Alice Hoffman would write.